# Issues encountered when importing wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl, tibco, axis

I created a web service "patients", and hosted it on Axis to get the WSDL:

WSDL code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/axis2" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
    <wsdl:documentation>getPatientDetails</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
            <xs:element name="getPatientDetails">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="args0" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="getPatientDetailsResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="RequestMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getPatientDetails"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ResponseMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getPatientDetailsResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="getPatientDetailsPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="getPatientDetails">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:RequestMessage" wsaw:Action="urn:getPatientDetails"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:ResponseMessage" wsaw:Action="urn:getPatientDetailsResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="getPatientDetailsSoap11Binding" type="ns:getPatientDetailsPortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPatientDetails">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getPatientDetails" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="getPatientDetailsSoap12Binding" type="ns:getPatientDetailsPortType">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPatientDetails">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPatientDetails" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="getPatientDetailsHttpBinding" type="ns:getPatientDetailsPortType">
        <http:binding verb="POST"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPatientDetails">
            <http:operation location="getPatientDetails"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="getPatientDetails">
        <wsdl:port name="getPatientDetailsHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:getPatientDetailsSoap11Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/getPatientDetails.getPatientDetailsHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="getPatientDetailsHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:getPatientDetailsSoap12Binding">
            <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/getPatientDetails.getPatientDetailsHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="getPatientDetailsHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:getPatientDetailsHttpBinding">
            <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/getPatientDetails.getPatientDetailsHttpEndpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

However, when I try to import the WSDL into TIBCO business works, I encounter issues:
The WSDL works on SoapUI tool and the java code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: what do want please express the things clearly.

Comment: I am able to import the WSDL into TIBCO. What is the issue?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Are you talking about TIBCO BusinessWorks? I just imported the WSDL into a BW project and it worked just fine.